# Submitting a form with jquery using a non-default action script

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to use jquery to submit a form, but instead of the default action script that is in the form, I would like to submit the post variables to different action script instead.

More specifically, this is my default form that works a particular way when a user clicks the submit button:

```
<form method="post" action="something.php" id="myForm"> 
</form>
```

What I am trying to do is submit the form above, but instead of using the default `something.php` as the action script I would like to use the `foo.php`.

Is this even possible? This is what I tried, with no success (the post vars arent getting passed to the `foo.php` page):

```
$.post('foo.php', '#myForm', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

I appreciate any suggestions on how to do this.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible of course, but you should pass a key-value pair, you can use [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray) method.

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.post('foo.php', $(this).serializeArray(), function(data) {
       // alert(data);
   }); 
});
```

If you have a click handler:

```
$('#element').click(function(e){
   //e.preventDefault();
   $.post('foo.php', $('#myForm').serializeArray(), function(data) {
       // alert(data);
   }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can I trigger this submit function? I am trying to manually trigger it... Because what I did is I placed the provided code in a click event so when a user clicks on some particular button, the code above gets executed, but the code above seems like an event listener, so I would need to trigger it manually...

Comment: @MiGusta If you have a click handler you don't need to listen to submit event, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to change where the form posts to, then change the `action` attribute with JavaScript.

```
$('#myForm').attr('action', 'foo.php');
```

Only use `$.post()` if you intend to change the default behaviour to use an XHR instead of a normal whole-page refresh.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well, I want to temporarily change the action attribute. I would like to default action script to remain...

Comment: @MiGusta Then you could store the original value, and replace it when you need to.

Comment: +1, thank you, I like your method a lot, however, I ended up using the other one because It requires less code modification. Your way is a simpler solution however :D